# SQL procedure usage / temporary table optimization

Tags: mysql, optimization, temp-tables

I have created a mysql database that stores several tree structure alike information. I have used nested sets approach for that. 
As I have created several procedures to create child node, retrieve child nodes of specific item and so on, to handle several tables those procedures are parametrized using table name. You know, one procedure to serve for several tables.

Anyway there is one table to store disk folder structure:

```
mysql> show columns from folder;
    +------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | Field      | Type                | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
    +------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
    | id         | bigint(20) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
    | priviledge | int(10) unsigned    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | name       | char(255)           | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
    | L          | bigint(20)          | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
    | R          | bigint(20)          | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
    +------------+---------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Companion index definition is as follow:

```
mysql> show indexes in folder;
+--------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table  | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+--------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| folder |          0 | id       |            1 | id          | A         |        3247 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| folder |          0 | R        |            1 | R           | A         |        3247 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| folder |          0 | L        |            1 | L           | A         |        3247 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| folder |          1 | LR       |            1 | L           | A         |        3247 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| folder |          1 | LR       |            2 | R           | A         |        3247 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+--------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

The query that is a bit problematic retrieves children of the selected parent node:

```
SELECT node.id, node.name, (COUNT(parent.id)-(sub_tree.depth + 1)) AS depth, node.r!=node.l+1 AS haschild
FROM <table_name> AS node, <table_name> AS parent, <table_name> AS sub_parent,
(
    SELECT node.id, node.name, (COUNT(parent.name) - 1) AS depth
    FROM <table_name> AS node, <table_name> AS parent
    WHERE node.L BETWEEN parent.L AND parent.R
    AND node.id = <parent_id>
    GROUP BY node.id
) AS sub_tree
WHERE node.L BETWEEN parent.L AND parent.R
AND node.L BETWEEN sub_parent.L AND sub_parent.R
AND sub_parent.id = sub_tree.id
GROUP BY node.id
HAVING depth = 1;


+----+-------------+------------+--------+---------------+------+---------+-------+------+----------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type   | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra                                              |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+---------------+------+---------+-------+------+----------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | system | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL  |    1 | Using temporary; Using filesort                    |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | sub_parent | const  | id,R,L,LR     | id   | 8       | const |    1 | NULL                                               |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | parent     | index  | R,L,LR        | LR   | 16      | NULL  | 3247 | Using index                                        |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | node       | ALL    | id,R,L,LR     | NULL | NULL    | NULL  | 3247 | Using where; Using join buffer (Block Nested Loop) |
|  2 | DERIVED     | node       | const  | id,L,LR       | id   | 8       | const |    1 | NULL                                               |
|  2 | DERIVED     | parent     | range  | R,L,LR        | L    | 8       | NULL  |    2 | Using where                                        |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+---------------+------+---------+-------+------+----------------------------------------------------+
```

Now the aforementioned procedure body looks like:

```
BEGIN
  SET @table_name = table_name;
  SET @row_id = row_id;

  SET @sql_text = concat(
'CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS _childs(INDEX(name)) ENGINE MEMORY AS SELECT node.id, node.name, (COUNT(parent.name)-(sub_tree.depth + 1)) AS depth, node.r!=node.l+1 AS haschild
FROM ',@table_name,' AS node, ',@table_name,' AS parent, ',@table_name,' AS sub_parent,
(
    SELECT node.id, node.name, (COUNT(parent.name) - 1) AS depth
    FROM ',@table_name,' AS node,',@table_name,' AS parent
    WHERE node.L BETWEEN parent.L AND parent.R
    AND node.id = ',@row_id,'
    GROUP BY node.id
) AS sub_tree
WHERE node.L BETWEEN parent.L AND parent.R
AND node.L BETWEEN sub_parent.L AND sub_parent.R
AND sub_parent.id = sub_tree.id
GROUP BY node.id
HAVING depth = 1;
');

  PREPARE stmt FROM @sql_text;
  DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS _childs;
  EXECUTE stmt;
  DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END
```

I am creating temporary table as workaround for further select statement as in mysql select can not take data from procedure returning rows.
Funny thing once I was able to inject information about 10000 files in few minutes, but can not recreate that for production use. Now adding files is terrible slow, traversing the file path using structure presented above takes several seconds per file. Running query without procedure is a lot faster.

I have already optimized heap / ram disk usage yet. And it seems that creation of the temporary table has no impact on performance. How can I further optimize mysql installation?

Comment: `SHOW CREATE TABLE`, `SHOW TABLE STATUS`, `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%buffer%';`.  From those, I may have an idea of where to go next.

Comment: `BIGINT` takes 8 bytes; `INT UNSIGNED` takes 4 bytes and allows values up to 4 billion; do you expect to exceed that?  Making the change would shrink the disk footprint by lots because you have lots of L, R, id, etc in the data and in indexes.

Comment: Don't use `CHAR`, use `VARCHAR`.  No, don't quote that myth about "fixed" length records being faster.

Comment: @Rick, well, changing types to what you suggested did speed up :) Table stauts is:  file       | InnoDB |      10 | Compact    | 91882 |             62 |     5783552 |               0 |     11599872 |   4194304 |          91745

Comment: Excerpt from show  %buffers%: | innodb_sort_buffer_size             | 1048576        |
| join_buffer_size                    | 262144         
| key_buffer_size                     | 16777216       
| myisam_sort_buffer_size             | 8388608        
| net_buffer_length                   | 16384          
| preload_buffer_size                 | 32768          
| read_buffer_size                    | 131072         
| read_rnd_buffer_size                | 262144         
| sort_buffer_size                    | 262144

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be using InnoDB?  Setting `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to 70% of *available* RAM is beneficial for InnoDB.

Comment: Memory buffer increased to 1.5G (using formula from http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27328/how-large-should-be-mysql-innodb-buffer-pool-size 1G shall be enought), but no change in performance.  Deleting all indexes increased speed but with every record added situation is worser and worser.  Just to explain a bit more, I am adding 100000 files to the DB by help of PHP script. For every file I traverse path using aforementioned procedure and when id of folder is found/created then insert to the another table is done.

Comment: appreciate your help yet still I can not understand why some time ago those 100k rows  was added in approx 1h while now it takes day or so (all the time the same machine - cpu i7 3.4G)

Comment: Creating a `MEMORY` table will eat into the RAM.  What is your value for `max_heap_table_size`?

Comment: There are multiple table scans in your query.  So the query will get slower as the table gets larger.

Comment: Move the `HAVING depth = 1` into the subquery.